# AngularJS documentation about compiler is misleading?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

In the [AngularJS documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler) it's written that:

> Compiler is an Angular service which traverses the DOM
>   looking for attributes. The compilation process happens in two phases.
>
> Compile: traverse the DOM and collect all of the directives. The
>   result is a linking function.
>
> Link: combine the directives with a scope and produce a live view. **Any**
>   **changes in the scope model are reflected in the view, and any user**
>   **interactions with the view are reflected in the scope model**. This
>   makes the scope model the single source of truth.

It seems to me that the part I highlighted in bold is a little bit misleading. It doesn't seem the case but it entirely depends on the directive implementation.

Consider the example in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LXAt7/820/)

```
angular.module('app', []);
var app = angular.module('app');
app.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.hi = 'Hello World';
  $scope.log = function() {
    console.log($scope.hi);
  }
});

app.directive('myDir', function() {
    return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<input value="{{hi}}" />',
    link: function($scope) {
        $scope.$watch('hi', function(newVal, oldVal) { 
        if(newVal === oldVal) return;
        console.log('value changed'); 
    });
    }
  }
});
```

with this view

```
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
      <my-dir></my-dir>
      <button ng-click='log()'>log scope</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

changes in the input element are not propagated to the scope (I'm fully aware of the directive ng-model and that with {{}} I'm just interpolating an expression one-way but what I'm contesting is exactly this: the documentation is not clear since the part I quoted entirely depend on the directive's implementation).

I suspect I'm missing something so my question is: what am I missing/misunderstanding?

Answer (score 0):

please see [my updated JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/aforni/LXAt7/822/).

I have added a new button:

```
<button ng-click='changeHiValue()'>Change Hi value from the controller</button>
```

And a new function in the controller:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.hi = 'Hello World';
  $scope.log = function() {
    console.log($scope.hi);
  }

  var index = 0;
  $scope.changeHiValue = function() {
    index = index + 1;
    $scope.hi = index;
  }
});
```

When the user click on the button, `index` variable is increased by 1 and assigned back to `$scope.hi`. So, evert time you click the button "Change Hi value from the controller" you see the value inside the text input is updated and if you click in the "log scope" the last value in the `<input>` field is printed.

So, the highlighted sentence in the documentation is correct. As you can see.

So, for example, if you click 3 times the button "Change Hi value from the controller" you see the number "3" inside the `<input>` field and if you click on "log scope", the number "3" is printed; **but** if you change the text inside the input field with something like "foo" and click "log scope" again, you will see "3" printed and not "foo". This is correct, because in the `myDir` template, you did not binded the variable `$scope.hi` in the `input` field. To do that you should use `ng-model` and not `value` attribute.

Comment: "(I'm fully aware of the directive ng-model and that with {{}} I'm just interpolating an expression one-way but what I'm contesting is exactly this: the documentation is not clear since the part I quoted entirely depend on the directive's implementation)"

Comment: Yeah, I read that part but, I mean, what is not clear about my answer? How can I help you better?